# Why would my bathtub spout stop leaking after fixing a water pressure issue?

Tags: plumbing, leak, bathtub

Something strange happened in my bathroom. For a few days the tub spout was leaking non-stop. During that time the water pressure had been low and there was no hot water. I thought that the leak was coincidentally due to a bad valve seat or washer.

However, once the water temp and pressure issues were fixed, the leak went away.

Anyone have any ideas how something like this can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Its evidently a pressure balanced valve. Most single handle valves are today.

Answer (score 0):

Spouts will not hold pressure.  They will stop water.  So if you have extra water in the pipe from valve to spout, the spout stopper will hold it (some don't even do that) but it will only hold pressure to a point (and some hold really no pressure).

So if your valve was pushing water to the spout due to some other reason then your spout would leak.  It could just be a tiny amount of water leaking out your valve.  This would go down to spout - gravity - your spout would intermittently leak as pressure builds past its limits.